# counting consecutive digits in a string

Tags: python, string

Want to perform the counting of consecutive digits in a string

for example if i have :

```
s = 'lucasdre246@gmail.com'
d = 'maria23antoneta2014@gmail.com'
```

Expected output for string `s`is 3.
And expected output for string `d` is 4 since is the max number of consecutive number of consecutive digits inside the string

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to get the consecutive numbers and get the longest group with `max` with `len` as `key`

```
s = 'lucasdre246@gmail.com'
digits = re.findall(r"\d+", s)
print(len(max(digits, key=len))) # 3
```

In case you can have a string with no numbers you can use the `default` parameter with an empty list for length 0

```
s = 'lucasdre@gmail.com'
digits = re.findall(r"\d+", s)
print(len(max(digits, default=[], key=len))) # 0
```

Comment: thanks! but if string doesnt have digits is failing, do u know how to solve it ?

Comment: @LucasDresl see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following function is what you looking for:

```py
def max_consecutive_digits(string):
    """
    Returns the maximum number of consecutive digits in a string.
    """
    max_consecutive = 0
    current_consecutive = 0
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit():
            current_consecutive += 1
        else:
            if current_consecutive > max_consecutive:
                max_consecutive = current_consecutive
            current_consecutive = 0
    if current_consecutive > max_consecutive:
        max_consecutive = current_consecutive
    return max_consecutive
```